# email validation is not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, email-validation

I have for a [frontendmentorchallenge](https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge) tried to do email validation for webpage. I have made a validation function to display error message when there is wrong email id entered. But it isn't working. I have given the html and JavaScript

```js
function validate() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var reg = "^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$";
  var result = reg.test(email);

  if (result == false) {
    alert("sorry");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <div class="inputgrp">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
    <img src="/images/icon-error.svg" alt="" class="error">
    <button type="submit"><img src="/images/icon-arrow.svg " ></button>

    <div class="errormsg">
      <small>please provide a valid Email</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I for one cannot email you. My email has 4 chars at the end. Change your quotes to `/` in the reg and remove the 3 so I also can email you: `var reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;`

Comment: that reg is a string and not a regexp

Comment: One problem is that `var reg=   "^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$";` does not create a regex, but a string. To create a regex use this: `var reg= /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;`

Comment: Why not just use the email type: `<input type="email" required />`, and have the validation done for you?

Comment: @Andy It is for a challenge. I have added his link back

Comment: yes the problem is solved.The problem is i  created a string instead of creating regx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem has been resolved. The problem is i created a string instead of creating RegExp.

So i changed `var reg = "^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$";` to the correct format as:

```js
var reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
```

Thanks for those who answered my question. I posting this answer because in future it might be helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 3):

To create a regex use

```
 var reg = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
```

you have created only a string, and there is no test method on string

Answer (score 0):

such as

```js
var reg= /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
var result= reg.test("abcd@gmail.com");
console.log(result)
// VM1103:3 true
```

Comment: 1. Please do not answer typo-type trivial questions that will have the answers in the comment to the question. 2. Please comment your answer with what you changed and why